# How do I write good tag wikis?

Tags: discussion, tags

I want to contribute to the community, but my tag edits keep being refused.

How can I write good tag wikis?

Answer (score 7):

There have been a great deal of bad suggested tag edits.

Here are a few examples:

**Python**

> Python is a programming language that lets you work more quickly and integrate your systems more effectively. You can learn to use Python and see almost immediate gains in productivity and lower maintenance costs.

This is hugely subjective! Tags are not for sharing your views.

**Windows**

> Windows is a highly popular computer operating system. The Raspberry
>   Pi, however, runs the Linux operating system.

Very unhelpful. Really says nothing about when this tag should be used.

**Waterproofing**

> Waterproofing is the process of protecting something from water. With
>   it's open design, the Raspberry Pi is at particular risk from the
>   dangers of water and electronics.

Totally unnecessary common knowledge.

Some of these I shouldn't have approved. And am rectifying the problem.

Editing tags is great, and everyone please keep it up. But please, *please* read the [blog post on how to write tag wikis](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/).

To summarise, **avoid stating common knowledge**, provide guidance on **when to use the tag** and **avoid generically defining the concept behind a tag**. These account for a great deal of the tags I've reviewed.

Again, let me say: **Please keep editing tags**. But bear in mind the points being raised here.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is going to be controversial (and certainly not directed at the OP) but...

If your tag wiki edits are all being refused, there is probably a good reason for it.

Maybe you are just not very good at writing tag wiki entries.

If that is the case, you might be better off looking for other ways to contribute.  For example

- **Answering questions** (that is the main purpose of the site after all.)
- Flagging spam posts
- Making cosmetic edits to questions and answers (code formatting, punctuation etc.)

Comment: How dare you! Only kidding, I know it's not directed at me :)

Comment: Very rarely are tag wikis rejected due to "bad writing." By far far far, the most common reason to reject tag wikis is that they simply describe what the tag/word *means* (common knowledge)... **rather than describing when to use the tag.**