# "Too many of your edits were rejected, try again in 7 days." What did I do wrong?

Tags: discussion, support, suggested-edits

When trying to edit a tag wiki:`Too many of your edits were rejected, try again in 7 days.`

Very useful.

After being here for just a few days, I can't edit any more tag wikis, which is essentially all I have been able to do so far, so 7 days of low activity for me. :(

I have made the 4th most edits overall, and I don't really know why I'm suddenly not allowed to edit any more (well, I do, but you know...).

I don't see what I've done wrong, I have spent a lot of time editing tag wikis in the last two days. *(We have a phrase on Wikipedia "Don't bite new users (especially without explaining to them)". I feel a tad as though I've been "bitten".)*

So to those who rejected the edits, what was I doing wrong? (I just want to get better!)

(Also, 7 days is a long time to learn some small point that I didn't quite gather!)

Also, if any SE staff/developers are around, why did I get redirected to a page with that text and nothing else? Litterally like:

```
<html><head></head><body>Too many of your edits were rejected, try again in 7 days.</body></html>
```

Normally you're very good for messages in bubbles and nice formatting..., and what I got given was incredibly unhelpful.

Comment: You can see your suggested edits under [the activity tab](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/46/dunsmoreb?tab=activity&sort=suggestions). They should list the rejection reason.

Comment: Some improvements/suggestions are offered here: http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/143/how-do-i-write-good-tag-wikis

Answer (score 8):

You've been doing a great job editing, please keep it up.

However, I have been trying to attract your attention, as some of your edits were not good enough and I wanted to discuss them with you. **Make sure you are reading the reasons why your edits are rejected.** Some of them were recommendations that you come to talk with my in chat.

Please read this question, that I posted a few days ago, which references tag wiki issues directly:

[How do I write good tag wikis?](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143/how-do-i-write-good-tag-wikis)

Comment: **Where are these reasons?** I have never found a reason why. In fact, I've never found anything at all when one of my edits has been rejected.

Comment: Okay, I've found them thanks to a link in the comments

Comment: Also, not trying to sound like I'm getting at you, but I can't really "keep it up" if I am blocked for 7 days :)

Comment: I'll attempt to do something about the ban now you have read the guidelines.

Comment: Thanks for that :) I've just put [a post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136915/tag-editing-limits-give-us-a-chance) up on SO Meta, but I wouldn't be surprised if in the end someone says "live with it", so if you can't, well, at least thanks for trying.

Comment: @ACarter, Jivings: you might be interested in: [Decision on rejected edits should be displayed as a notification to the editor](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120624)

Answer (score 5):

See this for more information: [Too many of your edits were rejected, try again in 7 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91392/too-many-of-your-edits-were-rejected-try-again-in-7-days) in particular the accepted answer:

> I just amended it to take into account your accepts.
> When deciding on whether we should ban or not, we now look at your last 7 days of activity.
>
> If (rejects - approvals / 3) > 5, you will be auto-banned.